# Splitting Pandas column into multiple columns without using str.split()

Tags: python, pandas, series

Is there a way in Pandas to split a column into multiple columns? I have a columns in a dataframe where the contents are as follows:

```
Test1   Test2   Salary
1   Akash   100_$
2   Akash   200_@
3   Yogi    300_%
4   Akash   400_$
```

I would like to split this into:

```
Test1   Test2   Salary  Currency
1   Akash   100_$   $
2   Akash   200_@   @
3   Yogi    300_%   %
4   Akash   400_$   $
```

Answer (score 2):

using [`s.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['Currency']=df.Salary.str.extract('(\W)')
#or df['Currency']=df.Salary.str.split("_").str[1]
```

> \W --> Any character that is not a letter, numeric digit, or the underscore character.

---

```
print(df)

   Test1  Test2 Salary Currency
0      1  Akash  100_$        $
1      2  Akash  200_@        @
2      3   Yogi  300_%        %
3      4  Akash  400_$        $
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you, the question said `"without str.split()"` so kept it as or in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the last character you can just use:

```
df['Currency'] = df.Salary.str[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `str.split` try following.

```
df['Currency']=df.Salary.str.replace(".*_", "")
df
Test1   Test2   Salary  Currency
0   1   Akash   100_$   $
1   2   Akash   200_@   @
2   3   Yogi    300_%   %
3   4   Akash   400_$   $
```

---

---

***OR(in case someone wants to use `str.split`:***

Could you please try following, using [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) here.

```
df['Currency']=df.Salary.str.split('_').str[1]
```

While printing `df` output will be as follows.

```
Test1   Test2   Salary  Currency
0   1   Akash   100_$   $
1   2   Akash   200_@   @
2   3   Yogi    300_%   %
3   4   Akash   400_$   $
```